# Boost python / importing module from thread requires ReleaseLock(). Why?

Tags: c++, c, boost-python

I develop a boost.python C/C++ program with multithreading.

In `main()`, I create a thread:

> PyEval_InitThreads();
>
> pthread_create( &id, &detached_attr, newThread, NULL );

・In newThread(), I call two Py_* functions.

> Py_Initialize();
>
> PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

Then I call a C++ function named `hoge()` in `newThread()`:

```
void hoge(){
    py::object main_module;
    py::object main_namespace;

    try {
        main_module = py::import("__main__");   //segmentation fault
        main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
    } catch (py::error_already_set const &) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    //Some boost python code
}
```

gdb back trace output is here.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x4032fe24 in __ctype_b_loc () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x4032fde8 in __ctype_b_loc () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Why does `import()` fail? I have no idea. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

--edit 12/12/28---

I solved this problem using the following method.

In `main()`, I execute

```
Py_Initialize();
PyEval_InitThreads();
PyEval_ReleaseLock();
```

Then I create the new thread. In the new thread, I execute

```
PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
CALL SOME PYTHON CODE
PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

But I don't know *why* this works now. Could someone tell me the reason?

Comment: I recommend trying simpler examples first.  For example, try to get pieces of the code running without threads.  Once everything works as expected (test it!) then try multithreading.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I could solve this problem.

Comment: How did you solve your problem ? I'm having the same issue ..

Answer (score 0):

Python, as many other interpreted languages, achieves thread-safety ([see this wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)) by utilizing a global interpreter lock (or GIL), that stops two python interpreter calls from operating in parallel. So, any python call you issue should first request the lock, execute your commands and then release the lock. You must follow that rule or you may crash the interpreter, like you did in your example. Notice that your function `hoge()` did not request the GIL, therefore the crash.

Now, wrapping your code with GIL request (or "ensure") and release function calls does not solve it all - you still need to make sure that, when you have 2 threads, that **both** will have access to the GIL. If you would not have released the GIL on the main thread, your second thread that actually does the python stuff would be blocked forever! Have you tried that? If not, you can just do it see what happens.

The correct solution - the one you found by yourself, is to acquire and release the GIL at every thread and make sure that you don't get stuck in one of the threads that have the GIL while the others starve.